# getTimezoneOffset() method return different time on localhost and on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone-offset

I have a function in which I am calculating the current user location time based on the Australian NSW timezone minus the local offset. So for example I want to compare an event starting time in Australian (NSW) local time vs my local time I am getting the correct value if I open the website on my localhost. However I am getting 1 hour different if I visit the website on the uploaded server (test environment). So if the correct time is 04:00 on localhost I am getting 05:00 on the test environment.

Here is my function:

```
var date = {

    formatFullDate: function(date, gmtTimeOffset) {
        var localDate = this.getLocalTimeFromAustraliaTime(date, gmtTimeOffset),
            month = this.addZeroToFront(localDate.getMonth() + 1),
            hour = this.addZeroToFront(localDate.getHours()),
            minute = this.addZeroToFront(localDate.getMinutes());

        return localDate.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute;
    },

    formatTime: function(date, gmtTimeOffset) {
    var localDate = this.getLocalTimeFromAustraliaTime(date, gmtTimeOffset),
        hour = this.addZeroToFront(localDate.getHours()),
        minute = this.addZeroToFront(localDate.getMinutes());

    return hour + ':' + minute;
    },

    addZeroToFront: function(whatever) {
        if (whatever < 10) whatever = "0" + whatever;
        return whatever;
    },

    getUTCtimeOffset: function() {
    var date = new Date();
    return date.getTimezoneOffset();
    },

    getLocalTimeFromAustraliaTime: function (date, gmtTimeOffset) {
    var gmtTime = new Date(date.getTime() - gmtTimeOffset*1000),
        localOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
        localDate = new Date(gmtTime - localOffset*60*1000);
    return localDate;
    }
}
```

Some general details for my specific case: 
Aus/NSQ time zone: UTC/GMT +10 hours 
Finnish timezone: UTC/GMT +3 hours
So there is 7 hours different between AUS/NSW and Finland and the result is correctly displayed on localhost but not on the test environment. I am not sure why there is 1 hour different between these 2 cases.

EDIT: 1

This is how I am displaying the current local time

```
var tr = $('<tr style="cursor:pointer; color: #000000" id="' + categoryId + '_' + raceNumber + '_nextRaceTr"/>')
                .append($('<td/>')
                    .append($('<p/>')
                        .html(date.formatTime(new Date(value.time), value.timezoneOffset))))
```

Where as time and timezoneOffset are the JSON response.

P.S - Dont pay attention if I am missing enclosing brackets or any other syntax error. I have only copied a small piece of code just to show how I am displaying the time on HTML.

Comment: So it is server side issue, not client side. What ever type of server you are using, you should set its time to the relevant one you wish, i guess

Comment: Alright. I will ask the backend guy in my team to look at the server time. However, lets say if I set the server time to UTC +3 wouldn't it be a problem if someone from US visit the site and see the result? Since I am comparing the AUS/NSW timezone to user's local time and displaying it according to the user location?

Comment: Is this code always running on the client (e.g. in a browser) or does this code actually run on the server (e.g. nodejs)?

Comment: @threed On client side.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `Date` object is *always* influenced by the time zone settings of the environment where it is running.  In most cases, that's the user's browser.  Users of different time zones will get different results running your code.

In general, you should beware of any code that follows a pattern like this:

```
var adjustedDate = new Date(someOtherDate.getTime() - someOffset);
```

You might think you're cleverly adjusting the behavior of the `Date` object to a different time zone, but in reality you're changing the referenced point in time and leaving the time zone the same!

Also, consider where you have:

```
var localOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

You might think you're getting the time zone offset for the user, but actually you are just getting the *current* time zone offset for the user.  Remember, `new Date()` initializes to the *current* moment in time.  The moment you're working with might have a completely different offset, depending on if the user happens to be in a time zone with [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) or not and whether it was in effect at that time.

As far as your code goes, it's a bit difficult to tell what you're after since you didn't give examples of your input.  You might want to take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which has most of the formatting functions you might be looking for.

BTW - I don't see anything in your code that would actually bind it to any of the [Australian time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you convert all times to UTC and store in that format. When you display a time for a user, you can convert to their local time from UTC. Just make sure that you do all calculations/conversions on the same machine on which you are going to display the time (e.g. if you are displaying dates in a webpage, don't calculate the local time on the server, send down an epoch timestamp to the browser and then convert it to local time using JavaScript).

```js
var d = new Date(1413409549000);
alert(d.toString());
```

Comment: The epoch timestamp response for time I get from JSON is in format 1380820800000. After that I am formatting the timestamp in a readable format using JS. I am not sure how do I go ahead with your approach? Any example in lieu with my question would be appreciated.